# Hibernate entity validation

Tags: java, hibernate, ejb

I would like to implement a custom  validator which would operate on the Entity level. Without additional  annotations on field level Ie something like :

```
@Entity
@MyValidator
public class Adress{
}

MyValidator{
public boolean validate(Object o ){
  ....

}

}
```

I would like to use The hibernate validation  system for this(or at least  i dont want to reinvent the wheel) Is it possible ?

Comment: This is a well documented feature - https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.0/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html#section-class-level-constraints

Comment: looks like an answer i would like to accept